# Need to identify current view fragment from pager adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, pager

We have to know the current fragment which is the visible mode in pager adapter, but unable to process.

```
for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
    if (fragment instanceof OffLineSyncedFragment && fragment.isVisible() && fragment.isVisible()) {
        ((OffLineSyncedFragment) fragment).confirmDeleteAlert(getActivity(), documentHelper, false, isDocument, null);
    }
    else if(fragment instanceof OffLineFailedFragment && fragment.isVisible()){

    }
}
```

This is my code which is not working.

Comment: give your fragments a tag and use that tag to identify the fragment

Comment: There are several ways to do this based on the purpose. If you can say why exactly you want to query the active fragment, I can provide the relevant solution.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` is the correct approach here. And as you have noticed, `onPageSelected(int position)` doesn't get called until the page is centered. So when the page is properly centered it will give you the fragment that is currently visible.,

Comment: Do you really think onPageSelected works in this case?

Comment: Yes it works fine when the page is changed to get the current fragment that is visible.

Comment: Please make a try, your approach will work if and only if there a list of fragments. In general case your approach will return the new instance of same fragment at that position which is nearly useless for any updates.

Comment: Yeam you are right it will only work if he have a list of fragments, which can be defined.

Comment: I generally do not prefer having list of fragments. It will create unnecessary memory overhead

Answer (score 0):

There is some ways to do it. first easy and straight you can set page change listener on your view pager :

```
  viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(final int i, final float v, final int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int i) {
        // If you are user FragmentPagerAdapter below is the right way to get fragment
        Fragment fragment= getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager_card_exchanger + ":" + i);

        if(fragment!=null){
            // Do your stuff here 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int i) {
    }
});
```

Or You can override the the fragment method as below:

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        System.out.println("VISIBLE");
    } else {
        System.out.println("GONE");
    }
}
```